# Splitting a string with no delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string like "My dog" into an array of:

```
| M | y | space char will be in here | D | o | g |
```

Here is my code:

```
String []in_array;
    input = sc.next();  
in_array = input.split(""); //Note this there is no delimiter 

for(int k=1; k < in_array.length; k++){
    System.out.print(" "+in_array[k]);
}
```

EDIT:

It only prints out "My"

Comment: So, what happends?

Comment: What is the question? Did it work? If not, what did it do wrong?

Comment: Well, on my computer, it prints out `My Dog`. Please re-test it. Does your input really contains:  -`My Dog`?

Comment: @RohitJain See my edit. I was using a Scanner.

Comment: @AdegokeA.. Using scanner.next() method only reads the next token. So it stops reading as soon as it encounters a `space`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, that's where I went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you see if "My", that is all you have in your `input` string. Did you use Scanner.next() ?

```
for(String s : "My dog".split(""))
    System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
{empty line}
M
y

d
o
g
```

Answer (score 9):

java.lang.String has a [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) that does exactly that.

Comment: -1 that gives you an array of `char`, not an array of `String`

Answer (score 4):

You only need one line of code for this:

```
String[] arr = input.split("(?<=.)");
```

The regex says to split *after* every character, so unlike splitting on blank, you don't get an initial blank element from the split.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Java code

```
String sourceString="My Dog";
char[] varArr = sourceString.trim().toCharArray();
for (char c : varArr) {
   System.out.print(c+" | ");
}
```